# Finding the center of a map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

Before this part, I made a master array that contain latitude, longitude and type form a public JSON API(https://data.buffalony.gov/resource/v5df-q4ru.json).

What I mean by master array is the following..

```
[["latitude","longitude","type"]...] // "..." represent more of 
//those single list containing latitude, longitude and type.
```

To find the center point, I will need to find the largest and smallest latitude and longitude in the master array. The center point will be the average of that largest and smallest value.

I did the following but I believe that there's a better way of doing it.

```
function findMapCenter(master){
  for (var key in Object.keys(master)){
    var lat = master([key]["latitude"]);  // [key] since it's a 
//array inside a array then finding the key string [latitude]
    var lon = master([key]["longitude"]); 
    var lat_max = Math.max(lat); 
    var lat_min = Math.min(lat);
    var lon_max = Math.max(lon);
    var lon_min = Math.min(lon);
    var total_max = (lat_max + lon_min);
    var total_min = (lon_max + lon_min);
    var average = (total_max / total_min);
  }
  return average; 
}
```

Get the average of longitude and latitude.

Comment: Does your current function give the results you're looking for? Note that comments on multiple lines need `/*` / `*/`, or `//` before each. It seems quite strange to `return average`, when `average` is only going to be the last value calculated

Comment: Passing in a single value to `max` isn't going to produce useful results. If you pass in an array you get `NaN` unless you use `apply`.

Comment: I edited the comments. I'm not familiar with apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` to get the latitude and longitude values into separate arrays, then apply those to min and max, and finally average them:

```
function findMapCenter(master) {
    var minLat = Math.min(...Object.values(master).map(({ latitude }) => latitude));
    var maxLat = Math.max(...Object.values(master).map(({ latitude }) => latitude));
    var minLon = Math.min(...Object.values(master).map(({ longitude }) => longitude));
    var maxLon = Math.max(...Object.values(master).map(({ latitude }) => latitude));
    return (maxLat + minLat) / (maxLon + minLon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.

Comment: What does `=>` do?

Comment: It's shorthand for `function(item) { return item.latitude }`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the array only once, which should be a little faster (not relevant if you never have large inputs). I'm writing my code based on the output received from the [API link](https://data.buffalony.gov/resource/v5df-q4ru.json) you mentioned:

```js
// Sample json
const json = [ { "latitude": "-11", "longitude": "-3" }, { "latitude": "-10", "longitude": "-30" }, { "latitude": "1", "longitude": "3" }, { "latitude": "2", "longitude": "-2" }];

function findCenter(json) {
    let [minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon] = json.reduce((a, b) => 
      [ +b.latitude  < a[0]  ?  +b.latitude  : a[0],
        +b.longitude < a[1]  ?  +b.longitude : a[1],
        +b.latitude  > a[2]  ?  +b.latitude  : a[2],
        +b.longitude > a[3]  ?  +b.longitude : a[3] ]
      , [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER]);
    return (maxLat + minLat) / (maxLon + minLon);
}

console.log(findCenter(json));
```

As a caveat, should your array be empty, this function will return:

```
[Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER]
```